# How to start the call on Skype with angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, call, skype

This is my code.
How can I pass the value customer.telephone?

```
<tr md-auto-select ng-repeat="customer in customers">
   <td>
     <a href="skype:{{customer.telephone}}?call">{{customer.telephone}}</a>
   </td>
   <td>{{customer.eMail}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://geek.michaelgrace.org/2010/03/create-html-link-that-starts-a-skype-call/

Comment: skype: "something" expects a username, callTo expects a number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ng-href` instead of `href` to make sure the `href` tag is interpolated correctly, and also make sure the `skype` scheme is in `$compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist`. By default, it isn't. See [the source](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/d077966ff1ac18262f4615ff1a533db24d4432a7/src/ng/sanitizeUri.js).

Comment: Thanks a lot. You were very precise

Answer (score 0):

Try `ng-href` instead of `href`:

```
<a ng-href="skype:{{customer.telephone}}?call">{{customer.telephone}}</a>
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref